# Docker always attaches local STDIN stream when running containers

Tags: docker

`docker container run` and `docker container exec` commands have the flag `--attach` for selecting which standard streams of our terminal emulator we would like to attach to the standard streams of the process running in the container. 
However, when I run `docker container run --interactive --attach stdout --name testubuntu ubuntu:bionic`, where I explicitly specify using the flag --attach that I only want the STDOUT stream of my terminal emulator to be attached to the STDOUT stream of the main process that starts in the container (Bash shell for this container), the STDIN stream of my terminal emulator still attaches to the STDIN stream of the process running in the container (Bash).

Can anyone explain why is that the case? If I remove `--interactive` flag, the STDIN stream does not attach to the STDIN stream of the process running inside the container, however, as far as I know, this flag just creates a memory buffer for the STDIN stream of the process running inside the container (Bash in my example), which makes Bash read data from the buffer instead of directly from the attached STDIN from the host.

Can anyone explain if --interactive flag besides keeping the STDIN data stream open, also attaches the local STDIN stream to the one of the process running inside the container?